# SSRS expression to get 2% report only daily

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SSRS report that run every day calculates employees interaction with sales sent report in excel .it will generate report how many times sales has been resolved by employees in a format of
[NAME , STATUS ,USERID . EDITDATE ]. what i am trying to achieve is i wont only to receive 2%
of the entire report daily for all username (Employee) . EXAMPLE if JOHN DOE oversaw 1000 sales today
i wont only 2% of what he adjudicated.

[image: [enter image description here]![1]]

Comment: show us your current query

Comment: To restate: The business problem is generating a quality control sample for review. You have a set of daily data. For each user in the set, you would like to have a random 2% of their data displayed. If a person only had 30 rows, 2% is 0 or 1 depending on how you deal with floating points. Have I captured the problem statement accurately?

Comment: @ billinkc yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [USERID] ORDER BY RAND()) AS Rn
FROM yourTable
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE  Rn = 2
```